# Uploading an image to server with phonegap (w/jquery ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to put together a small phonegap app to upload images to a collaboration site. I have looked over tutorial and API. So far I have the image captured but I am stuck on getting it to the server. I was hoping to use jquery for ajax it over. My jquery seems to stop the image capture btn working, when I take it out the btn works and captures an image. Is there another way other than jquery I can do this or I am just being a plonker and missing something? I am very new to phonegap.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });

}


function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

 function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

  var url = 'http://www.creativetree.co/phonegapupload.php';
  var params = {image: imageData};
  navigator.notification.alert('photo taken');    


  $.post(url, params, function(data) {

            // Display the selected image on send complete
            $('#image').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + params['image']);

        });
}

});
```

Answer (score -1):

The phonegap api has an example of this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: would the PHP be  similar to normal, I was using a $_POST earlier. What would I use to retrive the phonegap file transfer?

Comment: it would be something like ft.upload(imageURI,http://www.creativetree.co/phonegapupload.php", win, fail, options);

Answer (score -1):

posting an image as base64 via ajax is fine, I have done it in apps several times.
However, the tricky part may be encoding/decoding and making sure the php processes it correctly. Make sure the PHP doesn't expect an actual image (binary).